# Special HTML characters injected with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button (named Benjamin):

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Next &rarr;" />
```

And on a click event it says 'Loading' and does cool stuff. However, if there is a problem, I want it to change back to its original text while displaying the error message elsewhere.

```
$('input[name=btn_submit]').click(function() {
    $(this).val('Loading');

    // Logicy Stuff...

    // Error?
    $(this).val('Next &rarr;');

    return false;
});
```

Somehow, the literal text `&rarr;` is applied to the button, rather than the cool →. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html is evaluated with different rules that JavaScript is. Html entities only parsed by the html parser. Either use the unicode literal, like so:

```
$(this).val('Next \u2192');
```

Or better, keep track of the original value and then set it back:

```
var initalButtonValue = $(this).val();
$(this).val('Loading');

// Stuff

$(this).val(initialButtonValue);
```

Or perhaps even better, use HTML data attributes to store the states.

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Next &rarr;" data-normal-value='Next &rarr;' data-loading-value='Loading...' />
```

Then:

```
// Set to loading
$(this).val($(this).data("loading-value"));

// and back to normal
$(this).val($(this).data("normal-value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the actual → character in there instead of a HTML entity. Using an entity only works if you set HTML content - and form values are not HTML at all.

When using it inside `<input value="...">` it only works because in this case the entity is replaced while the HTML is parsed, so the value gets the actual character.

Comment: I tried your method, but even that literal character displayed as something else when coming from JS.

Comment: Then you probably have a charset/encoding issue. Is it an external .js file? If yes, ensure it has the same charset as used by your html page. Preferably UTF8.

Comment: It's inline JS. It's only needed for that one instance.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the value of the element with `$.data()` and retrieving it later:

```
$('input[name=btn_submit]').click(function() {
    $.data(this, 'value', this.value);
    $(this).val('Loading');

    // Logicy Stuff...

    // Error?
    $(this).val($.data(this, 'value'));

    return false;
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39thm/ (the `setTimeout` is just for demonstration)

Docs for `$.data()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data

Also you are using thr `$(this)` selector more than once, if you use it a bunch then it's a good idea to cache the selection:

```
$('input[name=btn_submit]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $.data(this, 'value', this.value);

    $this.val('Loading');

    // Logicy Stuff...

    // Error?
    $this.val($.data(this, 'value'));

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I saw the up and down vote from someone; any reason? I'd just like to be aware of problems with this code example.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the code for the character, you can add it to a JavaScript string with `.fromCharCode()`:

```
var s = "hello " + String.fromCharCode(1023); // just a made-up number
```

You can also embed characters in JavaScript strings if you know their hex code:

```
var s = "string \u1023 string";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='btn_submit']").click(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.data( "orgText", elem.val() ).val('Loading');       
    window.setTimeout( 
        function(){
            elem.val( elem.data("orgText") );
        }, 1000 );

    return false;
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCT85/)